# Need to add a loop in this code to circle back to the yes or no question when an invalid input is provided

Tags: python

I wanted to make a simple program that is built out the following way:

1. Ask for name, age, and gender
2. Print a sentence with that name, age and gender
3. If the sentence is correct, ask if the user wants to go again
4. If they want to go again, restart the function over
5. If they do not want to go again, quit the program
6. If the input of go again is not yes or no, inform the user and restart the go again question

The problem I am having is that I don't know how to restart the go again question without restarting the entire function. Will I need to create a separate go again function or use a while loop somewhere?

Here is my code:

```
#Take the input

def infofun():
    name = input("Please enter your name: ")
    age = input("Please enter your age: ")
    gender = input("Please enter your gender: ")
    gender = gender.lower()
    #Determine the output based on gender selection
    if gender == "male":
        ans = input(f"Your name is {name}, you are {age} years old and your are a man? (Yes/No) ")
        ans = ans.lower()
        # If answer is correct, ask if they want to go again
        if ans == "yes":
            goagain = input("I got it right! Want to go again? ")
            goagain = goagain.lower()
            # If go again is yes, rerun the function
            if goagain == "yes":
                infofun()
            # If go again is no, quit the program
            elif goagain == "no":
                print("Goodbye!")
            # Else print invalid input and restart the go again question. This is where I am lost
            else:
                print("Invalid Input. Please enter yes or no")
        # If answer is not correct, restart the function
        elif ans == "no":
            print("Let's try again")
            infofun()
        # Same as before. If input is invalid, restart the go again question
        else:
            print("Invalid Input. Please enter yes or no")
    # This is a continuation of the initial question. Same steps apply.
    elif gender == "female":
        ans = input(f"Your name is {name}, you are {age} years old and your are a woman? (Yes/No) ")
        ans = ans.lower()
        if ans == "yes":
            goagain = input("I got it right! Want to go again? ")
            goagain = goagain.lower()
            if goagain == "yes":
                infofun()
            elif goagain == "no":
                print("Goodbye!")
            else:
                print("Invalid Input. Please enter yes or no")
        elif ans == "no":
            print("Let's try again")
            infofun()
        else:
            print("Invalid Input. Please enter yes or no")
    else:
        print("Invalid input. Please enter yes or no")

infofun()
```

I would like for the `goagain` portion to start over if the input is anything other than yes or no.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](/q/23294658/4518341)

Comment: I suppose a deeper problem is that you should be using [guard clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_\(computer_science\)). Once you do that, adding input validation is easy (in the linked question). Also, you should [avoid repeating yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) in the male and female branches; instead use a variable for `'man'` or `'woman'`.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out [ask] for tips like making a [mre]; this is a bit too much code. For example, name and age aren't relevant to the problem. Really gender isn't either; you just need the "go again" section with something before it that you want to avoid repeating, like, say `print('Hello!")`, for a contrived example.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this with

```
valid_response = False
while not valid_response:
  response = input("I got it right! Want to go again? ")
  if response.lower() == 'yes' or response.lower() == 'no':
    valid_response = True
  else:
    print("Invalid response. Please enter 'yes' or 'no'.")
```

It will run as long as neither yes nor no is answered.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers quite rightly identify that some refactoring would be in order - in fact there is no end of improvement you could make to any code!

I thought I would offer the following as a minimal intervention, so that you can see what a small change can do to simplify your code a lot, while leaving it intact as possible in the hopes that this is less daunting than a wholesale rewrite.

The main thing is to introduce the function I have called 'ask'. It takes care of getting your yes/no answers and deals with invalid answers, and saves you writing the same logic over and over:

```
def ask(question=''):
    while True:
        answer = input(f"{question} ['yes', 'no'] ")
        if answer.lower() in ('yes', 'no'):
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid Input. Please enter yes or no")
    return answer=='yes'


def infofun():
    goagain = True #set to True initally so you get at least first game
    while goagain:
        name = input("Please enter your name: ")
        age = input("Please enter your age: ")
        gender = input("Please enter your gender: ")
        gender = gender.lower()
        #Determine the output based on gender selection
        if gender == "male":
            ans = ask(f"Your name is {name}, you are {age} years old and your are a man? (Yes/No) ")
            # If answer is correct, ask if they want to go again
            if ans:
                goagain = ask("I got it right! Want to go again? ")
                # If go again is no, quit the program
                if not goagain:
                    print("Goodbye!")
                    return
            else:
                print("Let's try again")
        # This is a continuation of the initial question. Same steps apply.
        elif gender == "female":
            ans = ask(f"Your name is {name}, you are {age} years old and your are a woman? (Yes/No) ")
            # If answer is correct, ask if they want to go again
            if ans:
                goagain = ask("I got it right! Want to go again? ")
                # If go again is no, quit the program
                if not goagain:
                    print("Goodbye!")
                    return
            else:
                print("Let's try again")
        else:
            print("Invalid Input. Please enter male or female")

infofun()
```

As a next step you might like to try writing a function along the lines of the 'ask' function here, but which generalises it to accept questions with answers other than 'yes' and 'no'.

Answer (score 0):

You can define function like below in infofun():

```
def va(q='are you fine y/n', val=('y','n')):
    while True:
        ans = input(f'{q} ')
        if ans in val: return ans
```

then use pattern like

```
if va() == 'y':
    print('glad to hear')
else:
    print('I feel a bit sad')
```